# Trying to hash my passwords but with no success

Tags: php, security, md5, salt

I am fairly new to php security, and for my site, I was a sign up and login, and I want to add md5 their passwords, but I can't find anywhere which has a clear guide on what needs to be added to the sign up, and what needs to be added to the login files, and/or the database, as I say I am fairly new to php in terms of web security, so I am in need of some help, here's part of what I have on my sign up form:

```
    $error = $user = $pass = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) destroySession();

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);


    if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br /><br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$user'";

        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)))
        {
            $error = "Username already taken<br /><br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES('$user', '$pass')";
            queryMysql($query);
            die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.");
        }

    }
}
```

I just need an example or a good guide of what I need to do to get it working correctly.

Comment: I do no salting, I just hash the password with SHA-1, and it's enough unless NSA puts an eye on my user database, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: I think you really should read about prepared statements and further about "high abstraction" solutions like Doctrine.

Comment: @Giacomo: No. You can crack SHA1 in the cloud in reasonable time (hours or days). Password should be always properly salted and hashed with strong hash function like sha512.

Comment: humph I know that... But you have to scale your security concern to the actual security needs. "My favourite pet forum" != "Online bank services". Unless you want to do the teacher's pet.

Comment: you shouldn't use functions like sanitizeString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking to salt and then hash your passwords.  Simply add a string of your choosing to the front (and if you wish, to the end) of your password before hashing it using MD5.

e.g.

```
$pass = 'mypassword';
$salt = 'S%gh3578';  //anything you want
$pepper = 'w890rrk'; //anything you want
$query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES('$user', md5('".$salt.$pass.$pepper."'))";
queryMysql($query);
```

This will store the password in the database using salted MD5 encryption that cannot be reversed using a lookup table of common passwords using unsalted MD5 encryption.

To check if a password is valid, you do something similar:

```
$passToCheck = 'something';
$correctMD5 = (retrieve hash from db)
if($salt.$passToCheck.$pepper == $correctMD5)
{    
   //valid login
} else {
   //login failure
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can for example md5($pass) before you insert and when the user logs in, you md5 again and check that the values are the same. There is no way to de-md5, so you will usually check the md5 input against the md5 DB value.

Comment: I agree that exceeding in security is useless, but things are not like you said. md5 can be reversed in the sense that, just suppose the user chooses a common password, then if you steal the DB, you can just check a list of widely used password with their md5 hashes and know what is the password that the user eventually uses for other web services. Though, this doesn't happen everyday. However, Think about it.

Comment: What I said here is true. You need to check the posted (on login) password's md5 with the md5 in the database. There is no way (programmatically) to de-md5! I know you can look up popular md5s on some websites, but that was not related to my comment. He was asking how to proceed...

Comment: you made it too easy. I'm too convinced that too much security is kind of troublesome and useless, but you can't give him the perception that md5($pass) = SAFE.